# Linq query to remove all data containing a specific matching number

Tags: c#, linq

I have data saved in my database that contains a `pointNumber` field that is an `int`.

I have a kendo grid and when I click on the "delete" button, I want to be able to delete the row where the `pointNumber` in my database matches the `pointNumber` of that row.

So far I an trying something like this:

```
public ActionResult Delete(PlanningViewParam data)
{
    List<PointData> Points = UserSession.GetValue(
        StateNameEnum.Planning, 
        ScreenName.Planning.ToString() + "Points" + data.ViewType,
        UserSessionMode.Database) as List<PointData>;

    int Number = 1;
    Number = data.Number;

    PointData point = Points.Where( a=> a.pointNumber == Number);
    if (point != null)
    {
       Points.Remove(point);
    }
}
```

The part I'm stuck on is this LINQ query:

```
PointData point = Points.Where(a => a.pointNumber == Number);
```

I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'PointData'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)?

What does that mean and how can I adjust my query?

Comment: Where returns a collection, and you are trying to save its result inside the PointData point variable, which is only for an instance. If you know for sure that your Condition will return only up to one result use SingleOrDefault. Points.SingleOrDefault( a => a.pointNumber = Number). It will return Null if it doesnt find any. But if there are more than one point with that Number it will throw an error. For removing items is probably better to use what DWright suggests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One adjustment you can make is:

```
Points.RemoveAll( a=> a.pointNumber == Number);
```

Then you don't have to obtain the result of a `Where` and do something with it.

Comment: Also, as a convention you should have the variable name for `int Number` be lower case: `int number`;  Type names are uppercase.  By having the variable lower case, it'll not look like Type in its own right.

Comment: if I use your solution, do I need to do a null check? What should I be checking that is not null?

Comment: You don't need to do a null check.  Since `Number` is not null, the comparison will only be true if `a.PointNumber` is not null (and equal to `Number`).  Try it out!

Answer (score 2):

The where method will return an Enumerable. You need to either pick the first value to delete

```
PointData point = Points.Where( a=> a.pointNumber == Number).FirstOrDefault();
```

or enumerate the list and delete over a for loop

```
List<PointData> points = Points.Where( a=> a.pointNumber == Number).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the options. yeah the thing is my data is saved in pairs, so two data rows could have the same pointNumber... like 1,1 ... 2,2...3,3... So I think the best option would be to enumerate the list to delete both data rows that contain the same point number? Thanks

Comment: Oh I am getting an exception for when I'm removing the points

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: Careful - `FirstOrDefault` can return null

Comment: @PhillyNJ He is already checking null in the if condition below

Comment: You dont need to call Where and then FirstOrDefault. FirstOrDefault can also receive a Func: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb549039(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also, in his requirement, it seems like he wants to delete all the items with the given number, not just the first one. If you asume he only has one item per Number, then is better to use SingleOrDefault.

Answer (score 2):

```
public ActionResult Delete(PlanningViewParam data)
{
    List<PointData> Points = UserSession.GetValue(
        StateNameEnum.Planning, 
        ScreenName.Planning.ToString() + "Points" + data.ViewType,
        UserSessionMode.Database) as List<PointData>;

    Points=Points.Where(p=>p.pointNumber!=data.Number).ToList();

}
```

Comment: It is LINQ way of doing it, which is better for a universal approach.  `RemoveAll` is a method on List but not IQueryable or IEnumerable, and only works on Lists.  `Where` is available on List (through IEnumerable) and IQueryable, and would optimize the query if it was accessing a database.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like `Points.Where( a=> a.pointNumber == Number);` is returning a collection. try `Points.Where( a=> a.pointNumber == Number).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: You dont need to call Where and then FirstOrDefault. FirstOrDefault can also receive a Func: msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb549039(v=vs.110).aspx